# Inserir conjunto de arquivo em 2 tabelas diferentes

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma situação que não consigo resolver, e gostaria da ajuda de vocês.

tenho um input do tipo file em meu formulário onde o usuário seleciona varias imagens de uma vez para fazer upload.

Eu gostaria de inserir 1 dessas imagens na tabela X e o restante na tabela Y, isso é possivel?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitProduto'])){

//Caminho para salvar
$caminho = "uploads/";

$produto = trim($_POST["produto"]);
$informacao = trim($_POST["informacao"]);
$categoria = trim($_POST['categoria']);
$subCategoria = $_POST['subCategoria'];

// Verifica Checkbox
if (isset($_POST['destaque'])) {
    $destaque = 1;
}
else {
    $destaque = 0;
}


//Inseri imagem
$sqlInsere = $database::query("INSERT INTO produtos (nome,descricao,categoria,destaque, sub_categoria) VALUES ('".$produto."', '".$informacao."','".$categoria."','".$destaque."', '".$subCategoria."')");

$sqlUltimoID = $database::query("SELECT * FROM produtos ORDER BY id LIMIT 0 , 1");
$rowUltimoID = $database::row($sqlUltimoID);

// lastInserId
$last = $rowUltimoID['id'];


for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES["fotos"]["name"]); $i++) {

    $nomeArquivo = $_FILES["fotos"]["name"][$i];
    $tamanhoArquivo = $_FILES["fotos"]["size"][$i];
    $nomeTemporario = $_FILES["fotos"]["tmp_name"][$i];

    if (!empty($nomeArquivo)) {

        $arquivoArray= explode(".", $nomeArquivo);
        $extensao = end($arquivoArray);

        $arquivo = $caminho.md5(time().rand(3212, 12043)).'.'.$extensao;

            if(move_uploaded_file($nomeTemporario, $arquivo)){
                $database::query("INSERT INTO produtos_fotos (id_produto, imagem) VALUES ('".$last."', '".$arquivo."')");
            } else {
                echo "Não foi possível enviar a imagem";    
            }
    }
}

$message = '<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Produtos cadastrados com sucesso!</div>';

}
?>
```

caso o usuario insira mais de 1 arquivo eu gostaria de adicionar 1 desses arquivos ao primeiro insert na tabela produtos e o restando no segundo insert na tabela produtos_fotos.

HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-bordered" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="inputDefault">Nome do produto</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="produto" placeholder="Digite aqui o nome do produto" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Selecionar categoria-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="inputDefault">Categoria</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <?php
            $categorias = $database::query("SELECT * FROM categorias_principal ORDER BY categoria ASC");
            echo '<select name="categoria" class="form-control">';
            foreach($database::result($categorias) as $categoria){
                echo '<option value="'.$categoria["id"].'">'.$categoria['categoria'].'</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Selecionar SUBCATEGORIA -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="inputDefault">Sub-Categoria</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <?php
            $categorias = $database::query("SELECT * FROM categorias_sub  ORDER BY subcategoria ASC");
            echo '<select name="subCategoria" class="form-control">';
            foreach($database::result($categorias) as $categoria){
                echo '<option value="'.$categoria["id"].'">'.$categoria['subcategoria'].'</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Seleciona as fotos-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="inputDefault">Fotos do produto <br /><small>Selecione quantas quiser</small></label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="fotos[]" multiple required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--- Informação/Descrição do produto -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="inputDefault">Informação do produto</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <textarea id="editor1" name="informacao"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Produto destque? -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="inputDefault">&nbsp;</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="checkbox" name="destaque" value="1"> Destaque
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="inputDefault">&nbsp;</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="submit" name="submitProduto" value="Cadastrar produto" class="btn btn-success">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: exatamente isso que eu quero saber @KaduAmaral, como eu faço para pegar 1 imagem entre 4 que foram enviadas pelo mesmo input do tipo file...

Comment: exato @KaduAmaral

Comment: Já editei com o HTML

Comment: Rafael está usando PDO?

Comment: sim, estou usando pdo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Breve explanação sobre multi-upload

Para trabalhar com upload de múltiplos arquivos é necessário informar o nome do *input* no formato de *array*:

```
<input type="file" name="upload[]">
```

Note que o valor do atributo possui chaves no final do nome `[]` isso indica que serão enviado vários valores nesse mesmo campo.

No lado do servidor você recebe esses dados na variável `$_FILES` com a chave do nome do campo, no nosso caso `upload` ficando `$_FILES['upload']`. Por defeito o PHP distribui esses arquivos da seguinte forma:

```
array(1) { 
    ["upload"]=>array(2) { 
        ["name"]=>array(2) { 
            [0]=>string(9)"file0.txt" // Arquivo 1
            [1]=>string(9)"file1.txt" // Arquivo 2
        } 
        ["type"]=>array(2) { 
            [0]=>string(10)"text/plain" // Arquivo 1 
            [1]=>string(10)"text/html"  // Arquivo 2
        } 
    } 
}
```

Então para acessa-los basta passar o indice do arquivo desejado após as propriedades:

```
$qtd = count($_FILES["fotos"]["name"]);

for ($i = 0; $i < $qtd; $i++) {

    $nomeArquivo = $_FILES["fotos"]["name"][$i];
    $tamanhoArquivo = $_FILES["fotos"]["size"][$i];
    $nomeTemporario = $_FILES["fotos"]["tmp_name"][$i];

}
```

Note que estamos passando o indice através da variável `$i`, assim podemos acessar cada arquivo que enviamos para o servidor.

#### Agora vamos tratar dos *inserts*.

Como sabemos que podemos acessar os arquivos passando indices, sabemos também que o primeiro índice de um *array* é `0` (salvo *arrays* associativos ou desordenados).

Armazene em uma variável a quantidade de arquivos enviados:

```
$qtd = count($_FILES["fotos"]["name"]);
```

Verifica se algum arquivo foi enviado e se for, armazene o primeiro na tabela produtos

```
if ($qtd > 0){
    // acessa o primeiro arquivo com o índice 0
    $nomeArquivo = $_FILES["fotos"]["name"][ 0 ]; 
    $tamanhoArquivo = $_FILES["fotos"]["size"][ 0 ];
    $nomeTemporario = $_FILES["fotos"]["tmp_name"][ 0 ];
    
    // Faça o upload do arquivo 
    $arquivoArray= explode(".", $nomeArquivo);
    $extensao = end($arquivoArray);
    $arquivo = $caminho.md5(time().rand(3212, 12043)).'.'.$extensao;

    if(move_uploaded_file($nomeTemporario, $arquivo)){
        
        $sqlInsere = $database::query("INSERT INTO produtos (nome,descricao,categoria,destaque, sub_categoria, imagem) VALUES ('".$produto."', '".$informacao."','".$categoria."','".$destaque."', '".$subCategoria."', '".$arquivo."')");
        $last = $database->lastInsertId(); // Pega o ID do último INSERT
    } else {
        echo "Não foi possível registrar o produto, falha no upload da imagem";
        exit;
    }
}
```

Depois verifique se foi enviado mais de um arquivo e se a variavel com o ID do produto cadastrado não está vazia:

```
if ($qtd > 1 && !empty($last)){
```

Então comece a registrar as imagens apartir da segunda que no caso é o ID 1

```
    // Inicia o loop apartir do indice 1, pois o indice 0 já foi registrado
    for ($i = 1; $i < $qtd; $i++) { 

        $nomeArquivo = $_FILES["fotos"]["name"][$i];
        $tamanhoArquivo = $_FILES["fotos"]["size"][$i];
        $nomeTemporario = $_FILES["fotos"]["tmp_name"][$i];

        // faça upload do arquivo

        // registre no banco

    }
}
```

O código todo fica assim:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitProduto'])){

    //Caminho para salvar
    $caminho = "uploads/";

    $produto = trim($_POST["produto"]);
    $informacao = trim($_POST["informacao"]);
    $categoria = trim($_POST['categoria']);
    $subCategoria = $_POST['subCategoria'];

    // Verifica Checkbox
    if (isset($_POST['destaque'])) {
        $destaque = 1;
    }
    else {
        $destaque = 0;
    }



    $qtd = count($_FILES["fotos"]["name"]);
    $last = false;
    $alert = 'danger';
    // Verifica se algum arquivo foi enviado
    if ($qtd > 0){
        // acessa o primeiro arquivo com o índice 0
        $nomeArquivo = $_FILES["fotos"]["name"][ 0 ]; 
        $tamanhoArquivo = $_FILES["fotos"]["size"][ 0 ];
        $nomeTemporario = $_FILES["fotos"]["tmp_name"][ 0 ];

        // Faça o upload do arquivo 
        $arquivoArray= explode(".", $nomeArquivo);
        $extensao = end($arquivoArray);
        $arquivo = $caminho.md5(time().rand(3212, 12043)).'.'.$extensao;

        if(move_uploaded_file($nomeTemporario, $arquivo)){

            $sqlInsere = $database::query("INSERT INTO produtos (nome,descricao,categoria,destaque, sub_categoria, imagem) VALUES ('".$produto."', '".$informacao."','".$categoria."','".$destaque."', '".$subCategoria."', '".$arquivo."')");
            if ($sqlInsere){
                $msg = "Produtos cadastrados com sucesso!";
                $alert = 'success';
                $last = $database->lastInsertId(); // Pega o ID do último INSERT
            }
            else 
                $msg = "Não foi possível cadastrar os produtos."
            

        } else {
            $msg = "Não foi possível registrar o produto, falha no upload da imagem";
        }
    } else $msg = 'Envie alguma imagem para continuar.';

    // Se foi enviado mais de 1 arquivo e a variavel do ID do produto não está vazia
    if ($qtd > 1 && !empty($last)){

        // Inicia o loop apartir do indice 1, pois o indice 0 já foi registrado
        for ($i = 1; $i < $qtd; $i++) { 

            $nomeArquivo = $_FILES["fotos"]["name"][$i];
            $tamanhoArquivo = $_FILES["fotos"]["size"][$i];
            $nomeTemporario = $_FILES["fotos"]["tmp_name"][$i];

            if (!empty($nomeArquivo)) {

                $arquivoArray= explode(".", $nomeArquivo);
                $extensao = end($arquivoArray);

                $arquivo = $caminho.md5(time().rand(3212, 12043)).'.'.$extensao;

                    if(move_uploaded_file($nomeTemporario, $arquivo)){
                        $database::query("INSERT INTO produtos_fotos (id_produto, imagem) VALUES ('".$last."', '".$arquivo."')");
                    } else {
                        echo "Não foi possível enviar a imagem";
                    }
            }

        }
    }

    $message = "<div class=\"alert alert-{$alert} text-center\">{$msg}</div>";

}
?>
```

Comment: @RafaelAcioly veja se consegue entender e utilizar o código. Fiz bem superficial, não testei o código, mas pelo que vi você não é um iniciante e já conhece algo de PHP, mesmo assim se estiver com dúvidas ou problemas estou a disposição.

Comment: No ultimo comentario de faça upload eu carrego novamente aquelas 3 linhas antes do primeiro insert? 
// Faça o upload do arquivo 
    $arquivoArray= explode(".", $nomeArquivo);
    $extensao = end($arquivoArray);
    $arquivo = $caminho.md5(time().rand(3212, 12043)).'.'.$extensao;

Comment: Faz o insert do caminho, assim como faz na outra tabela, adicione um campo para registrar o caminho do arquivo assim como faz no segundo insert.

Comment: Fiquei meio perdido com esse comentario, ainda estou tentando fazer meu cerebro mostrar como vai funcionar direitinho, rs

Comment: Sim da mesma forma como está no teu código. a única modificação ali é a do `for` que vem vez de `$i = 0;` ficou `$i = 1` para pular o primeiro arquivo que foi registrado na tabela produtos, mas caso queria registra-lo novamente deixe como estava.

Comment: sera que voce pode juntar meu código com o seu raciocinio? não estou conseguindo fazer isso! rs

Comment: @RafaelAcioly coloquei o código completo, mas como eu disse pode haver erros pois não testei, se der erro me deixe saber.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26115/discussion-between-rafael-acioly-and-kaduamaral).

Comment: melhor irmos pro chat! :)